# Make IObservable behave like it is pull-based

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm working on some old code that does not have IAsyncEnumerable, so I was trying to mimic IAsyncEnumerable behavior with IObservable. The issue is that IObservable is push-based and is giving results in random order.

Here is a very simplified version of what I want to achieve

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test().Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
    private static async Task Test()
    {
        var l = await GetFirstObservable()
            .SelectMany(i =>
            {
                return GetSecondObservable()
                    .Select(s => Tuple.Create(i, s));
            })
            .Take(3)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in l)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<T> Echo<T>(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        await Task.Delay(1);
        return value;
    }

    private static IObservable<int> GetFirstObservable()
    {
        return Observable.Create(async (IObserver<int> observer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        {
            foreach (var i in new [] {1, 2, 3})
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var e = await Echo(i);
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                observer.OnNext(e);
            }
        });
    }

    private static IObservable<string> GetSecondObservable()
    {
        return Observable.Create(async (IObserver<string> observer, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
        {
            foreach (var i in new[] { "A", "B" })
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                var e = await Echo(i);
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return;
                }
                observer.OnNext(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I want the following results to be in console:

```
1
A
B
2
A
(1, A)
(1, B)
(2, A)
```

Instead, the first observable does not wait for the second observable to complete, and I get  random results like:

```
1
A
2
A
3
B
A
B
(1, A)
(2, A)
(1, B)
```

Is it even possible to achieve this pull-like behavior, or should I just look for something else?

Comment: `should I just look for something else?` Yes, convert the observable to IAsyncEnumerable with System.Linq.Async's `ToAsyncEnumerable`. As for `IObservable is pull-based and is giving results in random order.` that's completely wrong. Observable is *push* and *preservers* order. It was built to process streams of events as if it was data so order and time is built into all Observable operators

Comment: Your code example doesn't help. What is this trying to do, why create observables by hand? Observable allows you to handle events with LINQ-like operators. Your code doesn't do that though. `SelectMany` is doing the job of eg [Observable.Zip](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Zip). `GetFirstObservable` does the job of [Observable.Interval](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableInterval) *and* what should be part of a `Select` that calls `Echo`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cannot use IAsyncEnumerable, because it is an old project - it is .net 4.8 . As for "pull-based" - yes, my mistake, changed to "push-based". In the real project instead of these two observables, I have two http calls, and the second call is parameterized with the results of the first call. As for "random order" - probably it is not enough explanation from my side - I mean that because all the observables in the example are async and are pushing their results simultaneously, the order of produced values is unpredictable

Comment: You can use [Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces/) to add IAsyncEnumerable to .NET Framework projects. That's not needed to pull or maintain order though, that's needed to pull asynchronously. Order is already maintained. If you really need to pull (do you? why?) you can use [Observable.ToEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh212132(v=vs.103)). That will break the architecture of the application though.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem anyway? Why do you think you need to pull? It's not about order. Pulling means your application no longer responds to events, it's polling for them. The threading changes too - by default an Observable pipeline uses one thread for all operators. After all, you don't need more than that to process a stream of events. You can specify that each operator uses a different thread though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in simple terms, the app needs to pull data page-by-page from one REST service and join it with page-by-page data from another REST service, apply some filtering and return top N results. To avoid reading all the pages (because only top N results are needed) I need some lazy logic that would stop pulling any additional pages. Thanks for directing me to Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces - I will try using it.

Comment: What you described is a "push" scenario. You push a URL to the operator that retrieves the pages which are then pushed to the next operator. If you need to combine the pages into a single dataset you can use `GroupBy` with the URL as the key.

Comment: Might be related: [Observable with backpressure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746475/observable-with-backpressure-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Could you edit the question and include a higher-level description of the problem that you are trying to solve? Trying to infer your intentions by reading the code is not easy.