# Slow down IObserver.OnNext while item handling is in progress

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have this code:

```
    var observers = new List<IObserver<string>>();
    var observable = Observable.Create<string>(observer =>
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
        return Disposable.Create(() => observers.Remove(observer));
    });

    using var subscription = observable
        .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000); // do some heavy work
            Console.WriteLine($"{item} processed.");
        }))
        .Concat()
        .Subscribe();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var item = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Console.WriteLine($"{item} generated.");
        foreach (var observer in observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(item);
        }

        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
```

It produces a sequence of values in the `for` loop. Each produced value must be handled asynchronously, and handling is heavy in comparison to producing. This leads to output like this:

```
aa2b2f95-18ef-49a7-b40d-2857bd8e43f3 generated.
4c3202f8-19f2-4d9a-a4bc-6db00cb29066 generated.
aa2b2f95-18ef-49a7-b40d-2857bd8e43f3 processed.
7d041f40-aacb-4d9d-bd7f-255c1edb0ed4 generated.
cee7004a-ab5f-42d1-a546-6e22793c415c generated.
4c3202f8-19f2-4d9a-a4bc-6db00cb29066 processed.
```

which is completely clear.
What I want to do is to slow down `OnNext`: it must not return control to caller if previous item is still being handled. All produced items are important, so skipping items while handling is in progress is not a solution.

How to achieve this? I'm newbie in Rx.
Async handling is taken from this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/459).

Comment: The feature you are searching for is called "backpressure". Here is a relevant question: [Observable with backpressure in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69746475/observable-with-backpressure-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, thanks a lot. I'll close this as a duplicate.